# Is it possible to join all the same terms into the same pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-structures

I have the following large pandas dataframe, which is composed of several terms:

```
type    name    exp
-------------------
feline  tiger  True
feline  cat    False
rodent  rabbit True
canine  dog    False
feline  puma   True
feline  bobcat False
```

Is it possible to join all the terms in the `name` column that have the same type in the `type` column into the same cell?. For example:

```
type    name                  exp
----------------------------------
feline  tiger cat puma bobcat True
rodent  rabbit                True
canine  dog                   False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `df.groupby`:

```
In [200]: df_grouped = df.groupby('type', sort=False, as_index=False)
```

First handle `name`:

```
In [202]: df_grouped['name'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
Out[202]: 
0    tiger cat puma bobcat
1                   rabbit
2                      dog
dtype: object
```

Now, handle `exp`:

```
In [203]: df_grouped['exp'].apply(any)
Out[203]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

---

Putting it together:

```
In [219]: df_grouped = df.groupby('type', sort=False, as_index=False).agg({'name' : ' '.join, 'exp' : any}); df_grouped
Out[219]: 
     type                   name    exp
0  feline  tiger cat puma bobcat   True
1  rodent                 rabbit   True
2  canine                    dog  False
```

---

To retain unique items only, pass a lambda to `name`:

```
df.groupby('type', sort=False, as_index=False)\
       .agg({'name' : lambda x: ' '.join(set(x)), 'exp' : any})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!... what is the function of the 'max' parameter?, also is it possible to add a `,` or a `'|'` to separate the terms?...I tried to `' | .join'`... However it did not worked

Comment: @J.Do The correct syntax is `'|'.join` or `', '.join`.

Comment: @J.Do My function uses `any` instead of max. Which is the same. Basically, it returns true if any of the constituent values are true, else false.

Comment: @J.Do Don't forget, you can accept answers if they helped :) Pick the one that helped you out.

Comment: Both answers where great. However, I found that in some cases I got repeated terms, for example: `flower  Azalea | Gardenia | Rose | Rose | Azalea`. How should I remove the duplicates and just let one term?, for example:  `flower  Gardenia | Rose | Azalea`

Comment: @J.Do Easy: `df.groupby('type', sort=False, as_index=False).agg({'name' : lambda x: ' '.join(set(x)), 'exp' : any})`

Comment: Thanks for the help, let me test it!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way.

```
In [797]: df.groupby('type', as_index=False).agg({'name': ' '.join, 'exp': 'max'})
Out[797]:
     type                   name    exp
0  canine                    dog  False
1  feline  tiger cat puma bobcat   True
2  rodent                 rabbit   True
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!... what is the function of the 'max' parameter?, also is it possible to add a `,` or a '|' to separate the terms?...I tried to `' | .join'`... However it did not worked

Comment: It should be `' | '.join`.